# Can I return a very long text stream with asp .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to generate quite large text data and return it in an ASP controller.

I tried to build the data in memory with a stringbuilder, but it fails:

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.

So, I would like to know how I can return the data as a stream built on the fly.

I could generate a temporary file and return a stream from that file, but I would like to know if there is a way to return a stream and then generate the next part of the stream as the client is requesting them?

Comment: You can write directly to the response stream by using `this.HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync()` in a loop

Comment: If possible, you should set the response's `Content-Length` header before you write the response stream.

Comment: How did you return long text stream? Share us a demo which could reproduce your issue.